# How to use custom look and feel for Swing application?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, classpath, look-and-feel

How to use custom look and feel jar files in Java project For Ex: Seaglass look and feel?

What are the required steps to successfully use any look and feel jar our project and how to *add jar file to class path*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am gonna use seaglass look and feel jar file to explain the answer, you can download the same  [here](http://seaglass.googlecode.com/svn/doc/downloads.html)

Step 1: First add the downloaded look and feel to your project classpath

Right click on your project in eclipse, go to Build path and select configure build path, Under Libraries tab choose Add External Jar and find your Jar file (seaglass jar file in this case). On pressing Ok it shoud appear under Referenced Libraries of your project.

Step 2: Register LookAndFeel class with UIManager

```
try {
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Add this code in the JFrame Class constructor.
 for other look and feel jar file replace "com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel" in the code its look and feel class (google it if you cant find).

You are done, Run your project and there you see the look and Feel you wanted,, Enjoy

Comment: *"on your project in eclipse"*  Realizing you asked this question to provide the answer, perhaps it would be best to apply the [tag:eclipse] tag since Eclipse is important for the 1st step.  For *deploying* Java desktop apps. to the general public, the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.  You would put the Look and Feel in the class path using an `extension` JNLP file (see the JWS link for more info. on both).

Comment: @AJ. I feel your comment is not relevent to the question except about eclipse tag

Comment: I thought it was relevant insofar as *"You would put the Look and Feel in the **class path**"* for time of deployment, as oppose to development.  After all, you don't develop apps. just for you, right?  You don't expect the end user to download Eclipse to run the app.?  It is at *that* (later, but inevitable) stage that JWS becomes the best way to add a PLAF to the (deployment-time) *class-path,* which really does seem core to the question.  +1 for adding the tag.  :)

Comment: @AJ. I provided the answer keeping programmers in mind who are finding difficult to use custom look and feel package in their project( my friend who is actually is). But whatever you said is absolutely right for deployment. optionally, we can export the necessary jars with our app right?

Comment: *"optionally, we can export the necessary jars with our app right?"*  It depends what you mean by that.  One Jar, or your jar + jars for the 3rd party APIs?  The latter is the more optimal way to distribute & often required by the licenses of the 3rd party APIs, the former is simpler.

Comment: @AJ. While exporting, eclipse gives an option to extract required code from libraries. This is more optimal right? instead of exporting complete 3rd party jar

Comment: *"This is more optimal right?"* 1) No, it is less optimal when it comes to updates for starters. Update a PLAF and the user may only need to download the ..60Kb of that PLAF.  Incorporate it into the main Jar and force the user to download a meg for every update.  2) The digital licensing information of the manufacturers (3rd party) Jar is missing. 3) The software will be in breach of the licensing requirements of some APIs.  *"instead of exporting complete 3rd party jar"*  That is the better option, for reasons that are hopefully becoming (more) clear now.